# problem with win 32 API programming

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, winapi

i just tried to compile and run a simple example which was found on **Programming Windows - Win32 API by Charles Petzold** here is the code :

```
#include <windows.h>
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("Hello, Windows!"), TEXT ("HelloMsg"), 0) ;
return 0 ;
}
```

and i got the following error :

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup   MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)
```

i am using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7. how to solve this problem?

is it because i am running some outdated piece of code in new OS if the win32 API for Windows 7 has been changed can anybody suggest me any resources to learn about win32 API for windows 7 with C/C++ or even assembly

Comment: make sure you have the Windows SDK installed(or whatever MS calls it now) to do Win32 development

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no doubt this is a duplicate question but i'll answer anyway.

You have created the wrong project type. You need to create a `Win32 Project` not a `Win32 Console Application`.